# Override hyphenation settings in caption

Tags: captions, hyphenation, fun

As tomorrow is April 1, I'd like to send a somewhat special interim version of my thesis to my supervisor. In the TeXbook, there is a chapter that is set up to make TeX fall in love with hyphenation. I like how it manages to hyphenate nearly every end-of line.

However, applying this to my document, I ended up with something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption} % not loading this "fixes" my problem

%\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false} % this also causes the problem to disappear, but I like the singlelinecheck

% handy commands from the TeXbook to apply all the best typographical rules regarding hyphenation
\hyphenpenalty=-1000
\pretolerance=-1
\tolerance=1000
\doublehyphendemerits=-100000
\finalhyphendemerits=-100000

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image}

        \caption{Figure Caption that Should not Be Hyphenated}
    \end{figure}

    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note how the text is nice and readable, but the caption is broken at every discetionary hyphen.

Apparently, this is somehow related to the way `caption` checks whether the caption fits into a single line and should be centered. Also, if I don't load the package at all, the problem disappears.

Is there a better way to fix this or to configure `caption` to use the normal hyphenation settings?

Comment: (not tested)  you can try, within the `figure` environment, to add `\hyphenpenalty=10000 \exhyphenpenalty=10000`.  `figure` gives a local group, so these settings should not persist outside that environment.  (but the same rules wouldn't carry over to a list of figures, if you have one.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Actually, the list looks fine. I was mostly wondering if there was an automatic way to do this, but of course I could use `\AtBeginEnvironment` for that. I just tested your suggestion and it works.

Comment: @wrtlprnft `\DeclareCaptionFont{nohyphen}{\hyphenpenalty=10000 \exhyphenpenalty=10000\relax}\captionsetup{font+=nohyphen}` (in the document preamble) should do the trick as well.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt thanks, that was the trick I was looking for!

Comment: Another way: `\let\svcaption\caption
\renewcommand\caption[1]{\bgroup\pretolerance=10000\relax\svcaption{#1}\egroup}`